# Inserting columns in ndarray created using numpy.genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-dtype

I created a `ndarray` from a txt file using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt). The txt file looks like:

```
2505000
10.316     1.936     0.025    0   15   0   0
10.316     1.937     0.028    0   15   0   0
10.316     1.943     0.028    0   15   0   0
10.316     1.954     0.022    0    9  58   0
10.316     1.955     0.026    0    9  58   0
```

I am running the reading the data with:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(fname,
                     skip_header =1,
                     dtype = [('X','f'),('Y','f'),('Z','f'),('V', 'i'),('T', 'i')],
                     usecols = (0,1,2,4,5))
```

I am now trying to duplicate the 4th column (the one I called `V`) and place it just after itself (before the last `T` column).

I know I can copy the column by doing `data['V']`, but how do I place this copy in between `V` and `T` (the 4th and 5th columns)? I had a look at [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), but I am not sure how to specify the index (the `obj` argument). I tried with `numpy.insert(data_copy, data_copy['T'],data_copy['V'])` with no luck (I received `IndexError: index 61 is out of bounds for size 20`).

Comment: You have to make a new dtype with the added field, and copy values by field name from the original array to the new one.

Comment: Look at `from numpy.lib import recfunctions`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27952861/901925

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I solved by combining recfunctions.append_fields and recfunctions.drop_fields, although I cannot specify an insert position. If no other solution comes up, and you would like to turn your comment to answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a new `dtype` with the added field, and copy values by field name from the original array to the new one.

`recfunctions` has functions to do this (and related actions):

```
 from numpy.lib import recfunctions
```

[numpy dtype error - (structured array creation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947763/numpy-dtype-error-structured-array-creation)